# When closing flex application it clears clipboard

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

When open flex application inside flash player in browser. Then copy to clipboard some data. Then close tab and as a result clipboard is empty. How to prevent clipboard clearing on application close?

**[UPDATE]**

It looks like it works correctly on Windows, but clears clipboard on linux and mac.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not possible - it is even written somewhere on Adobe site that the real system clipboard is not accessible for security... Therefore, you will just get a static variable, independent clipboard for you SWF file.

Only way to actually access the system clipboard is to use AIR runtime, which of course means desktop application stuff.

No solution, sorry.